# Is this simplification of GTK+ code correct?

Tags: c, animation, gtk3, cairo

I found the following [GTK+3](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/cairoimages/) code in Zetcode. It creates an animation using the cairo library while displaying an image:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* compile with 
 * 
 * gcc spectrum.c -o spectrum `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` 
 * 
 * */

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);

struct {
  gboolean timer;
  cairo_surface_t *image;
  cairo_surface_t *surface;
  gint img_width;
  gint img_height;
} glob;


static void init_vars()
{
  glob.image = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("beckov.png");

  glob.img_width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(glob.image);
  glob.img_height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(glob.image);  

  glob.surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 
      glob.img_width, glob.img_height);    
  glob.timer = TRUE;   
}

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{      
  do_drawing(cr);

  return FALSE;
}

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
  cairo_t *ic;

  static gint count = 0;

  ic = cairo_create(glob.surface);

  gint i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= glob.img_height; i+=7) {
      for (j = 0 ; j < count; j++) {
          cairo_move_to(ic, 0, i+j);
          cairo_line_to(ic, glob.img_width, i+j);
      }
  }

  count++;
  if (count == 8) glob.timer = FALSE;

  cairo_set_source_surface(cr, glob.image, 10, 10);
  cairo_mask_surface(cr, glob.surface, 10, 10);
  cairo_stroke(ic);

  cairo_destroy(ic);  
}

static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget)
{
  if (!glob.timer) return FALSE;

  gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
  return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  init_vars();

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), darea);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
      G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 325, 250); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Spectrum");

  g_timeout_add(400, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) window);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  cairo_surface_destroy(glob.image);
  cairo_surface_destroy(glob.surface);  

  return 0;
}
```

I achieve exatly the same result if I remove the **do_drawing()** function and move its code to the **on_draw_event()**, like:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* compile with 
 * 
 * gcc spectrum.c -o spectrum `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` 
 * 
 * */

struct {
  gboolean timer;
  cairo_surface_t *image;
  cairo_surface_t *surface;
  gint img_width;
  gint img_height;
} glob;


static void init_vars()
{
  glob.image = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("beckov.png");

  glob.img_width = cairo_image_surface_get_width(glob.image);
  glob.img_height = cairo_image_surface_get_height(glob.image);  

  glob.surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 
      glob.img_width, glob.img_height);    
  glob.timer = TRUE;   
}

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{      
  cairo_t *ic;

  static gint count = 0;

  ic = cairo_create(glob.surface);

  gint i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= glob.img_height; i+=7) {
      for (j = 0 ; j < count; j++) {
          cairo_move_to(ic, 0, i+j);
          cairo_line_to(ic, glob.img_width, i+j);
      }
  }

  count++;
  if (count == 8) glob.timer = FALSE;

  cairo_set_source_surface(cr, glob.image, 10, 10);
  cairo_mask_surface(cr, glob.surface, 10, 10);
  cairo_stroke(ic);

  cairo_destroy(ic); 

  return FALSE;
}


static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *widget)
{
  if (!glob.timer) return FALSE;

  gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
  return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  init_vars();

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), darea);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
      G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 325, 250); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Spectrum");

  g_timeout_add(400, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) window);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  cairo_surface_destroy(glob.image);
  cairo_surface_destroy(glob.surface);  

  return 0;
}
```

So... I wonder... Am I missing something here (loss of generality)?

Or was the call to **do_drawing()** in function **on_draw_event()** of the original code redundant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's correct on compiler's side.

But it's a good practice for functions to solve exactly one task. `do_drawing` is busy with drawing lines and pixels, `on_draw_event` is busy with processing events. Probably in this code snippet there is no real reason to make a separate function, but usually `on_draw_event` would be much more complicated.